# Java array not storing data given to it on initialization

Tags: java, arrays, netbeans

I'm a newb to Java and am trying to test a small quiz app with NetBeans.

I'm using JRadioButtons and button groups for multiple choice questions, and I thought to use an array to store all of the correct answers, as seen below.

```
private final javax.swing.JRadioButton correctAnswers[]= 
    {radioButtonOption1Question1,radioButtonOption1Question2,
    radioButtonOption1Question3,radioButtonOption1Question4,
    radioButtonOption1Question5,radioButtonOption1Question6};
```

***Edit**, this array is under the block of code Netbeans makes to initizialize all of the JFrame objects I have like the radiobuttons

However whenever I call on the array I get a null pointer exception error, and upon further investigation I found that the array was only storing 6 null values.

Why is this? Thanks

Also here's the loop sending the error when I run it

```
for(int i= 0;i<= 5;i++){
    if(correctAnswers[i].isSelected()){
    numCorrect++;
    }

    correctAnswers[i].setForeground(Color.green);
}
```

Comment: Are the `radioButton1Option1Question____` variables initialized?

Comment: It's never initialized.

Comment: Note that if you say `correctAnswers[] = {radioButtonOption1Question1, ...}`, and then **later** `radioButtonOption1Question1 = <something>;`, that doesn't affect what's in the array.  You've already put a `null` in the array, and the program doesn't keep track of where that `null` came from.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably not initializing your radiobuttons anywhere. Keep in mind that if you want to store them as final variables, you HAVE to do it immediately:

```
private final radioButtonOption1Question1 = new JRadioButton( [your options here] )
```

or in the constructor of your class.

Comment: @kbluee Netbeans automatically made a big block of code initializing all of the radiobuttons and other objects I put in the JFrame, then I just put the array initialization in under that, sorry if I was too vague

Comment: @user3704164 Could you paste somewhere example of this initialization code just to be sure?

Comment: I don't have it right now, but I do have Netbeans and here's what it made for a radio button of the same name `radioButtonOption1Question1 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();` and later `private javax.swing.JRadioButton radioButtonOption1Question1;`

Comment: @user3704164 `private javax.swing.JRadioButton radioButtonOption1Question1`; cannot be later in your code because it would not even compile. Please check this once again and remeber: if you want your buttons in arrar initialized, `new javax.swing.JRadioButton()` must be before correctAnswers[] initialization. The problem lies somewhere in the code you have not submitted here.

Comment: I have the code in front of me now and everything looks fine regarding what you said. I'd like to post it here but there's about 1000 lines of auto-generated UI stuff, and I don't know how to make a large spoiler field to hide it all

Comment: @user3704164 That's why auto-generation is BAD. Perhaps you could try at least handle this particular buttons manually by yourself?

Comment: I suppose I'll have to, or come up with something else. Thanks for your time though

Comment: Just out of curiosity, write me what was it when you find it.

Comment: For whatever reason after making the radio buttons final it works fine now, no idea why but I'll take it :D

Comment: I have now idea how you fixed it, but glad you worked it out :).

Answer (score 0):

What you have done is the equivalent of...

```
JRadioButton radioButtonOption1Question1;
```

Java recognizes it but cant find it's initialization so you've got to initialize everyone of those RadioButtons individually.

```
radioButtonOption1Question1 = new JRadioButton(args[]);
```